# Does Windows 7 come with the Windows Mobile Device Centre included?

Tags: windows-7, windows-mobile, mobile-phone

Does Windows 7 come with the Windows Mobile Device Centre included, or do I have to download and use [Windows Mobile Device Centre 6.1](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/downloads/microsoft/device-center-download.mspx)?

I've got a Palm Treo 750v running Windows Mobile 6, are there any known issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,

I had to download it separately, would post link but you already have it.

I can't remember what happened when I first plugged in my device without it :S

Comment: Ok, well, I am still on build 7048, however just done a bit of research for you and it doesn't *come* with it, but upon the first plug in, it will download and install it for you so you should have the latest supported version at install.

Comment: Downloaded 6.1 and it installed just fine on RTM. Phone is sync'ing nicely with Outlook. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  But some users have reported some issues. I havent tried it yet. I was using active sync in XP till now. Going to try it for the first time with the HTC Touch 3g tonigh. ;-)

Some blogs ask us to remove the installed version and reinstall (the downloaded version) if it crashes the first time when you connect the phone.

**Update**: I am using Windows 7 Ultimate (RTM) and it came with Windows Mobile Device Center. It didn't popup the first time I plugged in my mobile but I was able to find it it from Start -> All Programs.

Comment: I couldn't find it anywhere on my RTM Ultimate. Downloading 6.1 from the MS site worked though. Cheers.